# Sanitizing An Array

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form that is generated dynamically. The end users will be able to submit employee details to the database. So array $fname will contain all first names, $lname all last names ect. The arrays are then inserted into MySQL like so:

```
   $query = "INSERT INTO workers (date_added, department,fname, lname, rank)
   VALUES ";
    $fname = count(fname);
    for($i=0; $i<$employee_count; $i++) {
    $query .= "(NOW(),'$department','{$fname[$i]}','{$lname[$i]}','{$rank[$i]}'),\n";
  }
```

This works **great** until we have dangerous characters like single quotes e.g MC'Mahon, which makes the query to fail. I cannot use many normal functions such as mysqli_real_escape_string() since this is an array.
Is there a way to sanitize the array i.e escape any dangerous characters inside the arrays so that I sanitize each array before pushing it into them for loop that splits each array into strings that are then entered into MySQL?

Comment: You should consider using the [PDO library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: Your not inserting arrays into the DB, your inserting strings from an array. You can and should sanitize them.

Comment: I meant "you're", of course... twice.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use [`array_map`](https://www.php.net/array_map) before your `for` loop. That function applies a callback to each value of the array. In this case, the callback would be `mysqli_real_escape_string`.

```
$fname = array_map('mysqli_real_escape_string', $fname);
$lname = array_map('mysqli_real_escape_string', $lname);
$rank = array_map('mysqli_real_escape_string', $rank);
```

**Update based on comments below:**

To use `mysqli_real_escape_string` in procedural mode, you need to pass the "link" so you need to create a custom function:

```
function array_map_callback($a)
{
  global $dbc;
  
  return mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $a);
}

$fname = array_map('array_map_callback', $fname);
$lname = array_map('array_map_callback', $lname);
$rank = array_map('array_map_callback', $rank);
```

Comment: Thanks @Francois, the problem is that mysqli_real_escape_string() requires to be passed a database connection as one of the parameters so the above generates errors. I am not very sure what parameters are required by array_map so I am still figuring out how to pass the db connection.

Comment: @Bululu - Make sure that you establish a connection to MySQL above those lines using either `mysqli_connect` or `$mysqli = new mysqli();`. If you're using `mysql_connect`, you'll want to use `mysql_real_escape_string`. In either cases, you don't need to specify the "link" as if none is specified, it'll use the most recent connection hence why you should connect first.

Comment: @Franchois I have the database connection on top of the lines as follows. $dbc = mysqli_connect(localhost,root, user_password,some_db);   I think the $dbc need to be passed to mysqli_real_escape_string() function since it's a MySQL function,

Comment: @Bululu - See my updated answer. Apparently, the `mysqli_real_escape_string` function expects the "link" unlike the `mysql_real_escape_string` one.

Comment: @Franchois, thanks very much, works like charm! So I have voted and  accepted it as the correct answer.