# Escape for DB entire Array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm using PHP to write a script that will give me a MySQL query that I will then use directly from MySQL Workbench.

I fetch the data from a .csv and then I loop them to write the SQL syntax with PHP.

My problem is a way to escape every string inside the array to prevent that I get a corrupted query.

How can I run mysqli_real_escape on an entire array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, try to use PDO instead. With prepared statements, your variables are sent separately from the query and you don't have to worry about manually escaping the parameters.

Second, if you REALLY need to do this, use `mysqli_real_escape_string` with array map. Something like this should work

```
$escapedArray = array_map(function($val) use ($mysqli) {
        return is_string($val) ? $mysqli->real_escape_string($val) : $val;
}, $unescapedArray);
```

Or procedurally like this

```
$escapedArray = array_map(function($val) use ($mysqli) {
        return is_string($val) ? mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $val) : $val;
}, $unescapedArray);
```

The reason for this is simple. If any element of the array is not a string, escaping it will return `null`, so you return the element as is.

**EDIT:** For nested arrays, you will have to use `array_walk_recursive`, instead of `array_map`.

```
array_walk_recursive($varArray, function(&$val) use($mysqli) {
    $val = !is_string($val) ?: mysqli_real_Escape_string($mysqli, $val);
});
```

Comment: You fell into the same trap I did: he needs to generate SQL for a script that somebody else will use. PDO is out of the question, alas.

Comment: Which is why I also posted an alternative. :)

Comment: by golly gosh you did! Any reason not to use a straightforward foreach loop?

Comment: It doesn't escape anything... it returns the same strings :( With bot the examples.

Comment: @FezVrasta It will escape only special characters, and will NOT work with nested arrays.

Comment: Mine is a multidimensional array.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [array_map](https://www.php.net/array_map). Something like:

```
$safeArray = array_map ('mysqli_real_escape_string', $originalArray);
```

Comment: I was about to bring the smack down. Put that i after `mysql` please.

Comment: It gives me:  `mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in `

Comment: @FezVrasta: You can create a connection to some database that has the same collation and other features of the target database that your customer is using, and then pass in that connection argument.

Comment: You're quite right - it would have worked with `mysql_real_escape_string` but not with the `mysqli` version. There is a work-around here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6726800/sanitizing-an-array using a global to reference the mysqli link. But Ashwin's answer seems neater.

Comment: ok but how can I pass the second parameter? I have to use the example of @Ashwin Mukhija

Comment: @FezVrasta: use a language like Haskell that lets you do things like partial application.